# Отключение Drag блокирует прокрутку страницы на мобильных. yandex map API 3.0

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

День добрый, я создал карту и заметил что при отключении drag, на мобильных невозможно прокрутить страницу если вести пальцем по карте. Карта не перемещается, это верное поведение, но и страница не прокручивается и это проблема. Подскажите пожалуйста как это решить?
Мне нужно запретить перемещать карту, но нужна возможность прокручивать страницу.
Вот пример:
[Карта-codepen](https://codepen.io/smthusk/pen/yLRVKeb)

```
const LOCATION = {
center: [37.566072, 55.744637],
  zoom: '11'
};

initMap();
async function initMap() {
  await ymaps3.ready;
  const { YMap, YMapDefaultSchemeLayer, YMapControls,} = ymaps3;
  const {YMapZoomControl} = await ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-controls@0.0.1');

  map = new YMap(document.getElementById('map'), {location: LOCATION, behaviors: ['pinchZoom', 'dblClick']});
  map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer());
  map.addChild(new YMapControls({position: 'right'}).addChild(new YMapZoomControl({})));
}
```